# Ising Model, Graphs, and Cirq

Tags: circuit-construction, cirq

How would you explain, pictorially and without too much overhead, an interaction between the qubits on [this model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model) using Cirq?

I am interested in trying to map accurately the ansatz on Cirq to a graph using Python network's library.

I know this is a bit open-ended. What I am looking for are suggestions and examples to take a look at - besides the obvious one at Cirq's [docs.](https://cirq.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html)

Thank you.

Comment: Could you include the obvious one in Cirq docs with what you want additionally? That way it is less open-ended.

Comment: Done and Done!!!

Comment: Still missing link *"...on this model..."*

Comment: That sounds like a cool project. Do you wish to share your code?

Comment: We can work together on it if you like !